# iterate an array of object and separe comparing dates in es6

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8

I need to make a function to iterate an array of x objects then compare the date inside the objects and separate in different arrays so I can show separately in the HTML, this is my object:

```js
[{"id":1,"date":"2020-02-06","value":131},{"id":2,"date":"2020-02-06","value":135},{"id":3,"date":"2020-02-06","value":141},{"id":4,"date":"2020-02-05","value":151},{"id":6,"date":"2020-02-05","value":155}]
```

I want something like this:

```
obj1 = [{"id":1,"date":"2020-02-06","value":131},{"id":2,"date":"2020-02-06","value":135},{"id":3,"date":"2020-02-06","value":141}]

obj2 = [{"id":4,"date":"2020-02-05","value":151},{"id":6,"date":"2020-02-05","value":155}]
```

my code:

```js
// global variables
json = [{
  "id": 1,
  "date": "2020-02-06",
  "value": 131
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "date": "2020-02-06",
  "value": 135
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "date": "2020-02-06",
  "value": 141
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "date": "2020-02-05",
  "value": 151
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "date": "2020-02-05",
  "value": 155
}];
obj1 = [];
obj2 = [];


for (const x of json) {
  if (x.date != x.date) {
    obj1.push(x)
  } else {
    obj2.push(x)
  }
}

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

in result always the items push into the obj1..

any help is welcome.

Comment: x.date != x.date <-- um why are you comparing to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical solution for this is to group them by the key and push them to an array. Below is an example using Array reduce and Object.values to get it down to the two arrays.

```js
var items = [
  {"id":1,"date":"2020-02-06","value":131},
  {"id":2,"date":"2020-02-06","value":135},
  {"id":3,"date":"2020-02-06","value":141},
  {"id":4,"date":"2020-02-05","value":151},
  {"id":6,"date":"2020-02-05","value":155}
]

var dateGroups = items.reduce( function (dates, item) {
  dates[item.date] = dates[item.date] || []
  dates[item.date].push(item)
  return dates
}, {})

var results = Object.values(dateGroups)

console.log(results)
```

Comment: this seems good but how can i separate the two different results into different arrays dynamically?? because i need to accomplish this to make a chart with the results, thanks for the response

Comment: So reference index zero and index one into two different variables?

Answer (score 0):

You could goup by date and get an array of arrays.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, date: "2020-02-06", value: 131 }, { id: 2, date: "2020-02-06", value: 135 }, { id: 3, date: "2020-02-06", value: 141 }, { id: 4, date: "2020-02-05", value: 151 }, { id: 6, date: "2020-02-05", value: 155 }],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var group = r.find(([{ date }]) => date === o.date);
        if (!group) r.push(group = []);
        group.push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build an object that maps each unique date to its respective data items, having, basically, a group by date:

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"date":"2020-02-06","value":131},{"id":2,"date":"2020-02-06","value":135},{"id":3,"date":"2020-02-06","value":141},{"id":4,"date":"2020-02-05","value":151},{"id":6,"date":"2020-02-05","value":155}];

const groupedData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => ({
  ...acc,
  [curr.date]: [...(acc[curr.date] || []), curr]
}), {});

console.log(groupedData);
```

We also use above the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to make the code shorter.